# Scrapy concatenate array elements inside div in python

Tags: django, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to concatenate some text inside a `<div>` with `xpath` in `Scrapy`. The `div` has the next structure:

```
<div class="col-12 e-description" itemprop="description">
  "-Text1"
  <br>
  <br>
  "-Text2"
  <br>
  <br>
  "-Text3"
</div>
```

I've created a `ScrapyItem` in my `Spider`:

```
class MyScrapyItem(scrapy.Item):
     name = scrapy.Field()
     description = scrapy.Field()
```

If I do this,

`item['description'] = response.xpath('//div[@itemprop="description"]/text()').extract()`

everything gets mixed and separated by commas, like this:

`- Text1
,- Text2
,- Text3`

I think that's because `response.xpath('//div[@itemprop="description"]/text()').extract()` returns an array so it adds commas to separate the array items.

I'm trying to loop over the array and `join` each item inside the "description" `ScrapyItem` property.

This is what I'm trying:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    item = MyScrapyItem()
    item['name'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@itemprop="name"]/text())').extract()

    for subItem in response.xpath('//div[@itemprop="description"]/text()'):
        item['description'] = " ".join(subItem.extract())
```

I know it would work if I could do something like this:

```
for subItem in response.xpath('//div[@itemprop="description"]/text()'):
        item['description'] = " ".join(subItem.xpath('//div[@itemprop="something_here"]/text()')extract())
```

but the `div` that contains the text has no more tags inside.

Any help would be appreciated, it's my first `Scrapy` project.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what your question is. If it is how to I join together the items then you are along the right lines `item['description'] = " ".join(response.xpath('//div[@itemprop="description"]/text()').extract())`

Answer (score 1):

it is the other way around,
you have used

`item['description']  = response.xpath('//div[@itemprop="description"]/text()').extract()`
that will return a list
join the list directly

`item['description'] = " ".join(response.xpath('//div[@itemprop="description"]/text()').extract())`